# Работа с QSystemTrayIcon в нескольких формах

Tags: qt, qt5

Создал проект в qtcreator, в нем сделал несколько форм. В MainWindow сделал значок трея QSystemTrayIcon. Как теперь из другой формы работать с этим значком (например setIcon или showMessage).

Буду благодарен за конкретный пример в виде проекта qtcreator.

Comment: Передавайте указатель или ссылку, или из другой формы посылайте сигнал, который будет с setIcon/showMessage взаимодействовать

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.

Comment: Отпишитесь в ответе тогда как решили, а то на ваш вопрос наткнутся другие люди, а у вас только "спасибо, сам разобрался" :D

Answer (score 0):

В целевой форме делаем:

.h

```
public:
    QSystemTrayIcon *trayIcon;
```

В родительской открываем целевую и передаем указатель:

.cpp

```
if(!childForm->isVisible()){
    childForm->trayIcon = trayIcon;
    childForm->show();
}
```

Теперь в целевой форме можем делать например:

```
trayIcon->showMessage(title, text, QSystemTrayIcon::Information, 1000);
```